# R xts object subseting xts object with multiple days of intraday data for certain hours

Tags: r, subset, xts

Is there a way in xts object to do the same as below but for xts object with multiple days of intraday data? The below works like a clock but for one day of data. If I pass xts from 22nd to 26th it  does not. It seems like subseting intraday data in xts across multiple days is not possible to be done in one go but rather need to first split data per each day and then use this xts functionality. Is this correct?

```
indexTZ(tdata) = "GMT"
plotdata= tdata['20110822 10:00:00/20110822 12:00:00']

> plotdata= tdata['10:00:00/12:00:00'] works like swiss clock


> tail(plotdata)
                SYMBOL EX  PRICE              SIZE    COND CORR G127
2011-08-22 11:59:36 "BHP"  "N" "38370"            "185"   "1"  "0"  "0" 
2011-08-22 11:59:37 "BHP"  "N" "38380"            "314"   "1"  "0"  "0" 
2011-08-22 11:59:40 "BHP"  "N" "38390"            "675"   "1"  "0"  "0" 
2011-08-22 11:59:42 "BHP"  "N" "38390"            "119"   "1"  "0"  "0" 
2011-08-22 11:59:43 "BHP"  "N" "38390"            "359"   "1"  "0"  "0" 
2011-08-22 11:59:44 "BHP"  "N" "38400.7702920749" "42763" "1"  "0"  "0" 

 plotdata= tdata['10:00:00/12:00:00'] or 
 plotdata= tdata['20110822 10:00:00/20110826 12:00:00'] does not return expected xts 

tail(plotdata)
                SYMBOL EX  PRICE              SIZE   COND CORR G127
2011-08-26 15:59:53 "BHP"  "N" "38710"            "119"  "1"  "0"  "0" 
2011-08-26 15:59:55 "BHP"  "N" "38700"            "1004" "1"  "0"  "0" 
2011-08-26 15:59:56 "BHP"  "N" "38700.4838709677" "310"  "1"  "0"  "0" 
2011-08-26 15:59:57 "BHP"  "N" "38710"            "6"    "1"  "0"  "0" 
2011-08-26 15:59:58 "BHP"  "N" "38710"            "2"    "1"  "0"  "0" 
2011-08-26 15:59:59 "BHP"  "N" "38710"            "121"  "9"  "0"  "0"
```

Comment: plotdata=tdata['T10:05/T10:06']  I think that this code structure I have found is the correct way to deal with multiple days

Comment: possible duplicate of [xts tick data rolling subset](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7157174/xts-tick-data-rolling-subset)

Answer (score 2):

`xts` has time-of-day subsetting: [xts tick data rolling subset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7157174/xts-tick-data-rolling-subset/7158153#7158153)

`tdata['T10:00:00/T12:00:00']` should do.