# is it possible to plot a diagram with chartSeries() using as subset a timestamp?

Tags: r, timestamp, quantmod

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [xts tick data rolling subset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7157174/xts-tick-data-rolling-subset)

I ve got an xts object that contains daily timestamps

```
> ate
                           Close Volume
2011-09-06 10:35:03.800000  0.59   1000
2011-09-06 10:35:03.800000  0.59   1000
2011-09-06 10:35:03.800000  0.59    470
2011-09-06 10:35:03.800000  0.59   1000
2011-09-06 10:35:03.800000  0.59    100
2011-09-06 10:35:03.800000  0.59    430
2011-09-06 10:35:03.800000  0.59    570
2011-09-06 10:35:03.800000  0.59   1430
2011-09-06 10:35:03.800000  0.59     50
2011-09-06 10:35:03.800000  0.59   3000
2011-09-06 10:35:05.100000  0.59     10
2011-09-06 10:35:05.100000  0.59   2000
2011-09-06 10:35:05.100000  0.59   1000
2011-09-06 10:35:05.100000  0.59   2000
2011-09-06 10:35:05.100000  0.59    300
2011-09-06 10:35:05.100000  0.58   1490
2011-09-06 10:35:42.800000  0.59    300
2011-09-06 10:38:26.900000  0.58   1129
2011-09-06 10:38:26.900000  0.58   1500
2011-09-06 10:38:26.900000  0.58    500
     .         .             .       .
     .         .             .       .
     .         .             .       .
2011-09-06 13:41:03.900000  0.57    500
```

I wonder if there is a way to plot a diagram with `chartSeries()` using as subset the timestamp (for example from 11:00:00.0000 to 12:00:00.0000)?

Or if there is an other way to achieve this diagram.

Thanks in advance

Comment: See this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7157174/xts-tick-data-rolling-subset/7158153#7158153

Comment: thanks. the solution is `chartSeries(ate["T10:00/T13:30"])`